# Insert into table depending on value in column

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, pandas

I have a .csv file, for simplicity let's say it has 4 columns. I have to insert the row into a MySQL table dependent on the value in column 4, i.e. if column 4 value is 'x' the row should be inserted into table 'x'.
I have managed to automate the creation of the tables for every unique value in column 4 (currently 28 unique values).

How do I best approach the insertion?

Should I prep the data first and create new panda data frames for every unique value and then insert the data frames 1 by 1?
Should I make the distinction during the INSERT statement?

Somewhat new to python, if you see something else that's not how it should be, let me know.

Code for table creation:

```
import mysql.connector as msql
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from mysql.connector import Error
from UniqueRounds import unique_rounds

size = len(unique_rounds)

for i in range(size):
    element = unique_rounds[0]
    unique_rounds = np.delete(unique_rounds, 0)
    unique_rounds = np.append(unique_rounds, "`" + element + "`")

table_data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('PATH/file.csv',
                                      usecols=[0, 1, 13, 14]))

try:
    conn = msql.connect(host='localhost', user='root',
                        password='pw',
                        database='funding_research')
    if conn.is_connected():
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select database();")
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print("You're connected to database: ", record)

        for i in unique_rounds:
            try:
                cursor.execute(
                "CREATE TABLE " + i + " (Uuid varchar(255), Name varchar(255), FundingRound varchar(255), Amount BIGINT(255) DEFAULT NULL)")
                print("Table is created...")
            except Error as e:
                print("Table already exists")
except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
```

Comment: *I have to insert the row into a MySQL table dependent on the value in column 4, i.e. if column 4 value is 'x' the row should be inserted into table 'x'.* ... and not insert iа the value is other than 4? if so then there are 2 options. (#1) load everything into temptable then copy only matched data into working table. (#2) Ise LOAD DATA .. IGNORE with preprocessing and, if the row shouldn't be loaded, set PK or UK expression value to some existing one.

Comment: @Akina If the value is other than 'x', let's say 'y', then the row should be inserted into table 'y'. I have created a table for every unique value in column 4. So depending on the value of column 4 of each row, the row is to be inserted into the corresponding table.
Right now I'm trying to create dataframes for every unique value by using a dictionnaire and then appending the corresponding rows. That way I get dataframes that are already separated by the value of column 4 so I can simply insert those. I'm not sure if that's the best way...

Comment: *If the value is other than 'x', let's say 'y', then the row should be inserted into table 'y'.* No difference. The only point - one query per table (and, for option 1, one importing query).

Comment: @josh - Its always best to add the clarification in the question by editing it.